# How to access nested elements of json object using getJSONArray method

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "map": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "key": { "@xsi.type": "xs:string", "$": "ContentA" },
          "value": "fsdf"
        },
        {
          "key": { "@xsi.type": "xs:string", "$": "ContentB" },
          "value": "dfdf"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access the value of the `"entry"` array object. I am trying to access:

```
RESPONSE_JSON_OBJECT.getJSONArray("entry");
```

I am getting `JSONException`. Can someone please help me get the JSON array from the above JSON response?

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: I am writing in a Java class

Comment: Okay, I can't help but I have tagged your question with 'java' so that others who can help will be able to find it.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You have to decompose the full object to reach the `entry` array.

Assuming `REPONSE_JSON_OBJECT` is already a parsed `JSONObject`.

```
REPONSE_JSON_OBJECT.getJSONObject("result")
    .getJSONObject("map")
    .getJSONArray("entry");
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but it is very fragile if you want to get an element if it exists, otherwise return null (or behave civilly). Would be nice getString("result.map.entry[1].value") and get the value if it exists, otherwise null. Kind of a pain to check for existence of element at each level, then convert it and get sub-element.

Answer (score 12):

Try this code using Gson library and get the things done.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

JsonObject job = gson.fromJson(JsonString, JsonObject.class);
JsonElement entry=job.getAsJsonObject("results").getAsJsonObject("map").getAsJsonArray("entry");

String str = entry.toString();

System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It allows to parse JSON string into object data model. Please, see my example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class GsonProgram {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String response = "{\"result\":{\"map\":{\"entry\":[{\"key\":{\"@xsi.type\":\"xs:string\",\"$\":\"ContentA\"},\"value\":\"fsdf\"},{\"key\":{\"@xsi.type\":\"xs:string\",\"$\":\"ContentB\"},\"value\":\"dfdf\"}]}}}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        Response res = gson.fromJson(response, Response.class);

        System.out.println("Entries: " + res.getResult().getMap().getEntry());
    }
}

class Response {

    private Result result;

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return result.toString();
    }
}

class Result {

    private MapNode map;

    public MapNode getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(MapNode map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return map.toString();
    }
}

class MapNode {

    List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    public List<Entry> getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public void setEntry(List<Entry> entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(entry.toArray());
    }
}

class Entry {

    private Key key;
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Key getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(Key key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[key=" + key + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}

class Key {

    @SerializedName("$")
    private String value;

    @SerializedName("@xsi.type")
    private String type;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[value=" + value + ", type=" + type + "]";
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Entries: [[key=[value=ContentA, type=xs:string], value=fsdf], [key=[value=ContentB, type=xs:string], value=dfdf]]
```

If you not familiar with this library, then you can find a lot of informations in "[Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)".

Answer (score 5):

This is for Nikola.

```
    public static JSONObject setProperty(JSONObject js1, String keys, String valueNew) throws JSONException {
    String[] keyMain = keys.split("\\.");
    for (String keym : keyMain) {
        Iterator iterator = js1.keys();
        String key = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            key = (String) iterator.next();
            if ((js1.optJSONArray(key) == null) && (js1.optJSONObject(key) == null)) {
                if ((key.equals(keym)) && (js1.get(key).toString().equals(valueMain))) {
                    js1.put(key, valueNew);
                    return js1;
                }
            }
            if (js1.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
                if ((key.equals(keym))) {
                    js1 = js1.getJSONObject(key);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (js1.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
                JSONArray jArray = js1.getJSONArray(key);
                JSONObject j;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    js1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return js1;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
    String text = "{ "key1":{ "key2":{ "key3":{ "key4":[ { "fieldValue":"Empty", "fieldName":"Enter Field Name 1" }, { "fieldValue":"Empty", "fieldName":"Enter Field Name 2" } ] } } } }";
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
    setProperty(json, "ke1.key2.key3.key4.fieldValue", "nikola");
    System.out.println(json.toString(4));

}
```

If it's help bro,Do not forget to up for my reputation)))

Comment: here what is valueMain?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject("Your string here").getJSONObject("result");
JSONObject map = result.getJSONObject("map");
JSONArray entries= map.getJSONArray("entry");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: String can not be applied

Answer (score 1):

I'm also faced with this issue. So I solved with recursion. Maybe it will be helpfull.
I created method.I used org.json library.

```
    public static JSONObject function(JSONObject obj, String keyMain, String newValue) throws Exception {
    // We need to know keys of Jsonobject
    Iterator iterator = obj.keys();
    String key = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        key = (String) iterator.next();
        // if object is just string we change value in key
        if ((obj.optJSONArray(key)==null) && (obj.optJSONObject(key)==null)) {
            if ((key.equals(keyMain)) && (obj.get(key).toString().equals(valueMain))) {
                // put new value
                obj.put(key, newValue);
                return obj;
            }
        }

        // if it's jsonobject
        if (obj.optJSONObject(key) != null) {
            function(obj.getJSONObject(key), keyMain, valueMain, newValue);
        }

        // if it's jsonarray
        if (obj.optJSONArray(key) != null) {
            JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) {
                    function(jArray.getJSONObject(i), keyMain, valueMain, newValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

if you have questions, I can explain...

Comment: Eric how can you update your value if your `keyMain` is like: `key1/key2/key3/key4/0/key`. Please note the the `key4` is list so I'm accessing `0` element from the list. And then update the value from key. I'm asking this because `keyMain` can have same value on different locations in `JSON`.

Comment: keyMain is like: key1/key2/key3/key4/0/key - you mean like ("key1.key2.key3",newValue)?? to search by path?

Comment: Let say I want to update `"fieldValue":"Empty"` to  `"fieldValue":"Nikola"`
and I have the location `key1/key2/key3/key4/0/fieldValue`. Here is the Json:           
`{
  "key1":{
    "key2":{
      "key3":{
        "key4":[
          {
            "fieldValue":"Empty",
            "fieldName":"Enter Field Name 1"
          },
          {
            "fieldValue":"Empty",
            "fieldName":"Enter Field Name 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: So in this json you have 2 "fieldValue":"Empty", which you want to change?

Comment: if you want change both of them just use my example of code..I think I got what you need man. I will add answer. if it will helpful press up for my reputation..

Answer (score -2):

I would also try it this way

1) Create the Java Beans from the JSON schema

2) Use JSON parser libraries to avoid any sort of exception

3) Cast the parse result to the Java object that was created from the initial JSON schema.

Below is an example JSON Schema"

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 478.68, "last" : 478.68, "buy" : 478.55, "sell" : 478.68,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 51033.99, "last" : 51033.99, "buy" : 51020.13, "sell" : 51033.99,  "symbol" : "¥"},
}
```

---

### Code

```
public class Container { 

    private JPY JPY;

    private USD USD;

    public JPY getJPY ()
    {
        return JPY;
    }

    public void setJPY (JPY JPY)
    {
        this.JPY = JPY;
    }

    public USD getUSD ()
    {
        return USD;
    }

    public void setUSD (USD USD)
    {
        this.USD = USD;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [JPY = "+JPY+", USD = "+USD+"]";
    }
}


public class JPY
{    
    @SerializedName("15m")
    private double  fifitenM;

    private String symbol;

    private double last;

    private double sell;

    private double buy;

    public double getFifitenM ()
    {
        return fifitenM;
    }

    public void setFifitenM (double fifitenM)
    {
        this.fifitenM = fifitenM;
    }

    public String getSymbol ()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol (String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public double getLast ()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast (double last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public double getSell ()
    {
        return sell;
    }

    public void setSell (double sell)
    {
        this.sell = sell;
    }

    public double getBuy ()
    {
        return buy;
    }

    public void setBuy (double buy)
    {
        this.buy = buy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [15m = "+fifitenM+", symbol = "+symbol+", last = "+last+", sell = "+sell+", buy = "+buy+"]";
    }
}


public class USD
{
    @SerializedName("15m")
    private double fifitenM;

    private String symbol;

    private double last;

    private double sell;

    private double buy;

    public double getFifitenM ()
    {
        return fifitenM;
    }

    public void setFifitenM (double fifitenM)
    {
        this.fifitenM = fifitenM;
    }

    public String getSymbol ()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol (String symbol)
    {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public double getLast ()
    {
        return last;
    }

    public void setLast (double last)
    {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public double getSell ()
    {
        return sell;
    }

    public void setSell (double sell)
    {
        this.sell = sell;
    }

    public double getBuy ()
    {
        return buy;
    }

    public void setBuy (double buy)
    {
        this.buy = buy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [15m = "+fifitenM+", symbol = "+symbol+", last = "+last+", sell = "+sell+", buy = "+buy+"]";
    }
}


public class MainMethd
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonIOException, JsonSyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Documents\\file.json"));
        String res = obj.toString();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Container container = new Container();
        container = gson.fromJson(res, Container.class);
        System.out.println(container.getUSD());
        System.out.println("Sell Price : " + container.getUSD().getSymbol()+""+ container.getUSD().getSell());
        System.out.println("Buy Price : " + container.getUSD().getSymbol()+""+ container.getUSD().getBuy());
    }

}
```

Output from the main method is:

ClassPojo [15m = 478.68, symbol = $, last = 478.68, sell = 478.68, buy = 478.55]

Sell Price : $478.68

Buy Price : $478.55

Hope this helps.