# How to get value from nested JSON object in a generic way in Java

Tags: arrays, json, rest-assured, nested-json

I want to fetch value of Column, Tag & Status attribute from below json string in a generic way.

```
[
  {
    "HoldTag": {
      "Employee": {
        "Column": "0",
        "Tags": [
          {
            "Tag": "2345"
          }
        ],
        "Status": "3",
        
      },
      "Flag": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Searching google `how to extract value from json rest assured` might help you. We're not coding service, so pls add your attempted code.

Comment: I have tried below code 
JsonArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(JsonresponseString);

Comment: what do you mean by "generic way"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access nested elements of json object using getJSONArray method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898768/how-to-access-nested-elements-of-json-object-using-getjsonarray-method)