# how to get the nested item of the json object using Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jsonnode

I have the following json file `test.json`

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "123",
  "title" : "Test",
  "properties" : {
    "_picnic" : {
      "type" : "boolean"
....
```

I am able to get the first level value of the key using the following code. E.g. for `type` I get `object`

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        String exampleRequest = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            exampleRequest = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/test.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(exampleRequest);

            String type = jsonNode.get("type").asText();
            System.out.println(type);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // System.out.println(exampleRequest);


    }
```

However I do not get any response when I try to get the value for the second level. E.g. if I do

```
String type = jsonNode.get("_picnic").asText();
System.out.println(type);

OR the whole object e.g.

String type = jsonNode.get("properties").asText();
System.out.println(type);
```

I tried doing `properties._picnic` or `properties[0]_picnic` but no luck.

Comment: Maybe this could help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898768/how-to-access-nested-elements-of-json-object-using-getjsonarray-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for that method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText()) states (emphasis mine):

> Method that will return a valid String representation of the container value, **if the node is a value node** (method isValueNode() returns true), **otherwise empty String**.

Per the snippet of json text you shared, both `"properties"` and `"_picnic"` are *objects* not *values* so you are getting an empty string. It seems you'd need to use the [get](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(java.lang.String)) method:

```
jsonNode.get("properties").get("_picnic").get("type").asText()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is getting the value of type but why dont it gives me a block fro `jsonNode.get("properties").get("_picnic").asText()` or `jsonNode.get("properties").asText()`

Comment: I already explained this in my answer, but I'll update to clarify a bit.

Comment: Okay so you mentioned `get` but did not use it. Could you add this with the answer too. To get the respective objects use 
`String type = String.valueOf(jsonNode.get("properties"));` and `String type = String.valueOf(jsonNode.get("properties").get("_picnic"))`;

Comment: I did show an example of get in my original answer. `String type = String.valueOf(jsonNode.get("properties"));` would not be correct since in the JSON you posted `"properties"` is an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to simplify this code. Just call `getText` with a starting node and a variable list (array) of paths. It will determine if it need to check for object or array.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

public class NestedJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String exampleRequest = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            exampleRequest = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("src/main/resources/test.json"),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(exampleRequest);
            System.out.println(getText(jsonNode, "type")); // object
            System.out.println(getText(jsonNode, "properties", "_picnic", "type")); // boolean
            System.out.println(getText(jsonNode, "stuff", "0", "foo")); // bar
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getText(JsonNode node, String... path) {
        return getText(node, 0, path);
    }

    private static String getText(JsonNode node, int cursor, String[] path) {
        if (node == null || path == null || path.length == 0)
            return null;
        if (cursor == path.length) {
            return node != null ? node.asText() : null;
        }
        if (node.isObject()) {
            return getText(node.get(path[cursor]), cursor + 1, path);
        } else if (node.isArray()) {
            return getText(node.get(Integer.parseInt(path[cursor])), cursor + 1, path);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Modified `test.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "id": "123",
  "title": "Test",
  "properties": {
    "_picnic": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
  "stuff": [
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it and report back.

Comment: I think eventually I am looking for this kind of solution but instead of passing the arguments hardcoded, it would be nice to use the code to find if the coming item is an array or object and accordingly call the function.